# Django - using 1-1 relationship method to create two different user profiles, same authentication

Tags: django, authentication, model, relationship, profile

I have a Django project in which I have currently used the default user authentication process, and extended it to allow for user profiles. I now want to create profiles for two different types of users, e.g. User type 1: = WP. User type 2: = W.

I have looked at some of the suggested solutions but wanted some specific guidance on my particular scenario and code.

As I understand it, there are three ways of attempting to do this
1. Proxy Model
2. 1-1 Relationship Method (extend the user model)
3. Custom User Model.

I want to use option #2 - 1-1 Relationship Method and avoid the other two, with the objective being to 
a) allow users to log in
b) allow a user to specify if they are user type 1 (WP) or user type 2 (W)
c) If a user is user type 1 (WP) they are directed to a WP profile, and if a user is user type 2 (W) they are directed to user type 2 (W) profile.

I currently have this in my models.py (for users)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django import forms


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Would I be able to approach it by creating two different models for the two different required profiles instead,like below?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django import forms


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

class WP(User):
    WP_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=300)

class W(User):
    company=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    requirements=models.TextField(max_length=300)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

My views.py looks like this, and I call the profile page, so again, would I create logic that called either profile 1 or profile 2 page, depending on what type of user it is?

**views.py**

```
#USERS (register) view.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages #this allows us flash messages for testing
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .forms import UserUpdateForm
from .forms import ProfileUpdateForm

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

#Here we create python classes and they create html forms for us
#We want a registration form...so we can use the user creation form that already exists in Django

def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        #this UserRegisterForm is created in forms.py and inherits from UserCreationForm (the ready made form)
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) #create a form that has the data that was in request.POST
        if form.is_valid(): #is the form valid (do you have a username like this already, passwords match?
            form.save()#this just saves the account, hashes the password and it's all done for you!
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account created for {username}, you can now login.')
            return redirect('socialmedia-moreinfo')

    else:
        form =UserRegisterForm() #if the form input is invalid, render the empty form again

    #above we are creating a blank form and rendering it to the template
    return render(request, 'users/register.html',{'form':form})
#different types of messages message . debug, inf success warning and error

@login_required #this is a decorator (adds functionality to an existing function)
def profile(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request,f'Your account has been updated')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:   
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)


    context={
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }

    return render(request,'users/profile.html',context)
        #add a login required dectorator that django provides
        #we want a user to be logged in to view this profile view
        #see the very top to import decorators
```

My problem is that I am trying to avoid the custom user model route (for which there are plenty of tutorials) but for teaching purposes want to approach it this way.

**My questions are:**
1. How can I solve this, (what changes need to be made in models and views) to create two user profiles using the 1-1 relationship method.

2. Am I approaching this completely wrong? Should I quit this approach and go the custom user route?
3. Finally, are there any recommended tutorials for beginners, for creating projects with multiple users. I could find none! There is one on youtube, but includes REACT, which complicates the process and tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just updated code, as had the wrong models in there. I've used the 'extend user model' option, but cannot quite see how this ties in with the views and how to re-direct users. For instance, now that I have the two users, how do I re-direct them on registering?

Comment: There are way too many questions in here, but I'd definitely suggest using different profiles and keeping only a single, minimal (or default) `User` model and associating each instance with whichever type of profile it needs to have. One approach is to define a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), e.g. `MyUser.profile`, that will check which 1-to-1 relation exists and return it.